# Deploy a self-hosted SignalR backend to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I made a web application with the following architecture :

A React.js frontend (only client-side javascript, no Node.js server)

A SignalR self-hosted backend in a C# console app

I would like to deploy my setup to Azure but I am a complete newbie with Azure.

I should be fine deploying the front-end by following a tutorial like [this one](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-use-webmatrix/)

but I can't find any resource about deploying a SignalR self-hosted backend.

I found some resources discussing about a ASP.NET MVC SignalR web application hosted in IIS on Azure, but not about a **self-hosted** one.

Should I be using an App Service for my backend? Any caveats?

Thank you for enlighting me

Comment: "*Should I be using an App Service for my backend?*" - no right answer to this. App service is a hosted service solution. There are also web/worker role cloud services, virtual machines... lots of ways to host/run software within role instances and virtual machines as well. This will completely depend on which features you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Which method is best suited for my Self-hosted SignalR backend service? I don't want to run it in IIS and I want it to be very scalable since I could need to manage thousands of websocket connections at the same time

Comment: There is no "best suited."

Comment: @DavidMakogon Your replies are really not helping you know, what is the point.

Comment: Sigh. My point is that this question doesn't work here, because there is no best answer. If you want my advice: Go to azure.com and look at the different ways you can run apps in Azure: App Service (websites), Cloud Services (windows VMs that are managed for you), Virtual Machines (VMs you manage yourself). See what they're about. Then make a logical choice, or ask a more concrete question. StackOverflow isn't a discussion board, and this question requires discussion.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? None of these answers seem useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can but it is not best performance wise, to host your SignlarR on IIS.

Reasons for not hosting in IIS include:

> Environments where IIS is not available or desirable, such as an
>   existing server farm without IIS. The performance overhead of IIS
>   needs to be avoided. SignalR functionality is to be added to an
>   exising application that runs in a Windows Service, Azure worker role,
>   or other process.

In Azure you can run it as for example:

**App Service** ([read more)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites).

**Windows Service** ([example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-self-hosted-in-6ff7e6c3) and [read more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwasham/archive/2011/03/30/migrating-a-windows-service-to-windows-azure.aspx)).

**Worker role** ([read more](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/host-owin-in-an-azure-worker-role))

Comment: This isn't really accurate. You can run it in many ways, not just the ones described.

Comment: I agree that I **don't** want to run it in IIS, that is why I self-hosted it. On my dev machine, it is running as a Windows Service but how should I host this program in Azure?

Comment: @ibiza I it's better to convert your windows service to a Worker Role.

Comment: @Rikard Thanks, is a Worker Role hosted in a Cloud Service on Azure, rather than in an App Service? I red that an App Service is easier to maintain (in terms of deployment, scalability...) than a Cloud Service

Comment: Worker Role is hosted in a Cloud Service. If App Service is easier then you should choose that.

Comment: @Rikard well...App Service means hosted in IIS right? No possibility to run code not in IIS in an App Service?

Comment: Yes, so Cloud Service then :)